# How to merge 5-6 Existing apps on itunes Apple store into a single framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, enterprise

My client have 5-6 ios apps already on App Store,they want us to create a central framework which should merge all existing apps ,and with the help of that framework new apps could be created,this question may sounds dumb ,as i am new to ios development ,i need to know is this really possible in iOS..PLease help.

Comment: I think you need some precise definition of 'merge' and 'framework'.  (For example, you could create a library that included functionality from existing apps and build on that but if you're thinking of using pre-built apps as building blocks, it's not likely to work.)

Comment: There is no way of answering your question since you don't even discuss what type of applications, API, frameworks your clients have in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate what all the apps have in common. Then try to develop classes, that are used in all of them.